# Is it possible to create multiple log files with JCL?

Tags: java, logging, apache-commons-logging

I am trying to save the results of a specific action in the server side of my application so that i can use the logs for mining purposes. To send the results to db in runtime for each action causes too much transaction load. So I want to save them first as logs and dump the log files into database periodically. The application uses jcl for logging. However, i could not find any solution for this in jcl. Is it possible?  Also any other idea for this purpose will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I suggest you to go for [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) and logback? Logback has [RollingFileAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) that can solve your task. Logback has a native binding for SLF4J

Comment: Thank you very much. I used a solution for log4j (http://www.calazan.com/how-to-log-to-multiple-log-files-with-log4j/) and i'm also going to try the logback solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

JCL (Jakarta Commons Logging) isn't a logging implementation, it's just an API.  It delegates to an "real" logger behind the scenes such as `java.util.logging` or log4j. That's what you need to configure to get your log file handling the way you want it.